# MRF and Textures

Tags: texture, interpolation

I am pursuing my research in Texture Interpolation. After digging deep into it, I'm stuck at a point. It is proven that textures can be modeled as Markov Random Fields and that each texture can be synthesized from a collection of neighborhoods. How exactly do we get these neighborhoods that can characterize a texture and if we have them, how can we synthesize the texture back ? And, how does MRF help in any of the above ? Can anyone please provide me with a explanation that helps a layman understand concepts above ?

Comment: I would be more modest on general claims about "textures can be modeled as". I would rather say "some (restricted) famillies of textures can".

Comment: It would help if you could add some links to explain the concepts you are referring to, like Markov Random Fields and texture neighborhoods. Otherwise, we're just guessing what you're talking about.

Comment: Do you mean "Texture Synthesis" in which a large texture can be generated from a small exemplar?